# define configurations when publishing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

There's a custom made application already in production environment for client A. Now my boss decided that he also wants to sell it to client B.

The app relevant software design guidelines are the following:

- Using clickonce to publish the application (easy to publish updates).
- The database connection sting is isolated on a code file
- All the design styles are defined on App.xaml

Consider the codebase will be the same, which approach should I use to publish the application to different clients?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to deploy with click once, this means you have an IIS server running. You could use a WebService for the configuration. How you handle the configuration transfer at that point is entirely up to you (Username/Passworded service, Licensed service, etc.). The WebService allows you to transfer pretty much everything that is serializable, so it should do the work for a configuration.